# The slot setShowGride doesn't work in my app

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, qt5.9

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ebv4qvol49rrqd3/SP.rar?dl=0) is the program and here is [the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybIBV.png).

Here is also the code for the `showGridAction` (where I see issues in that) inside the: `void MainWindow::createActions()` function (in `MainWindow.cpp`):

```
showGridAction = new QAction(tr("&Show Grid"), this);
    showGridAction -> setCheckable(true);
    showGridAction -> setChecked(spreadsheet -> showGrid());
    showGridAction -> setStatusTip(tr("Show or hide the spreadsheet's"
                                       " grid"));
    connect(showGridAction, SIGNAL(toggled(bool)),
            spreadsheet, SLOT(setShowGride(bool)));

#if QT_VERSION < 0x040102
    // workaround for a QTableWidget bug in Qt 4.1.1
    connect(showGridAction, SIGNAL(toggled(bool)),
            spreadsheet->viewport(), SLOT(update()));
#endif
```

My questions:

1- First I think the part `#if QT_VERSION < 0x040102` until `#endif` is not needed anymore, because I'm using Qt 5.9. Do you think so too?

2- That code doesn't work in effect. As you can see from the screenshot above, checking and unchecking the `Show Grid` option makes no changes! How to make it work for the app please?

3- There is a slot in the code named `setShowGride(bool)`. Where is it from? It won't be highlited when I click it and also takes me nowhere when I press `F2` on it! It's probably the source of the issue  for the option above not to function.
 How to fix it please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo in the code. If it is fixed the app runs correctly. Use `setShowGrid` not `setShowGride`.

And about that part of the code, yes, it's not needed because you are using Qt 5.9.